# Cleric/Sorcerer multiclass help

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, multi-classing

I'm looking for some help with multiclassing as I don't yet fully understand it. My plan is to multiclass my Cleric 4 next level into sorcerer

My question here being What would be the best multiclass route for a war cleric level 4? I was thinking about picking up sorcerer next level so I could access some meta magic skills by level 8 and quicken a hold person and inflict wounds and do some major damage, among other things. How useful would this be in terms of gameplay? From my minor understanding, this seems like a very utilitarian build but I'm interested in hearing about any unseen benefits and hindrances.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I did some minor edits to your question to hopefully make it more readable.

Comment: Could you further clarify what you are looking to do in the build, and what you want to compare it to? It looks like you're comparing cleric 4/sorc 4 to cleric 8 in terms of ability to control the battlefield, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: I feel this is too broad or opinion based.  You're basically asking "Is this a cool/powerful build idea?" Which is really doesn't have a right answer.  This feels more like a discussion/forum question than an SE question to me.

Answer (score -1):

Multiclassing increases the breadth of a character, but only adds indirectly to the depth/power.

This answer is written on the basis that "best" is roughly equivalent to "most powerful". Obviously, seeking a more "flavorful" or "rp-friendly" type of build requires a different evaluation.

---

For a casting class, the utility and power of higher level spells vastly outweighs almost any benefit gained from multiclassing.

While 5th edition does add multiclass progression on your "Spells per day" amounts, you still only have spells-known available as if you were a single-classed character in each class.

A Cleric 4/ Sorcerer 4 can only cast 2nd level spells in each class.

A Cleric 8 has access to 4th level spells. At 9th level, you add 5th level spells.

The power of higher level spells generally outweighs having a more variety with a few extra lower-level spells. Added to that, there is significant duplication between the spell lists.

---

For a martial class, the trade-off can be more balanced. While it remains true that many of a class' higher level abilities are significantly more powerful, the level of power is rarely comparable to that of a new level of spells. With a smaller degree of power trade-off, the increased versatility can make sacrificing the class capstone abilities seem more worthwhile, particularly so when a campaign might not be expected to last for 20 levels.

Comment: In terms of flavor and rp it would be better/ make more sense to muliclass cleric wizard but at this point I feel it's not in my best interests to multiclass my cleric. Thank you for your help.